# image_send_to_editor filter - Unwanted paragraphs and line breaks

Tags: images, filters, editor

I'm using image_send_to_editor to filter the output the images that are inserted to my posts. The filter works perfect except for when I'm updating/saving the post. A new paragraph with a line break inside will appear under the inserted picture on save. So if I save the post 5 times, 5 paragraph tags will appear.. Have a look at the output is after e few saves:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<figure class="alignnone"><img src="http://www.travelingthegoodvibes.dev/content/uploads/2015/01/IMG_4761-682x1024.jpg" alt="TEST">
    <figcaption>
        <p class="image-description"><span>TEST: </span>test</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p></p>
```

annoying, huh? This is how the filter looks:

```
function title_caption_image($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) {
    $src  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, $size, false );
    $html5 = "<figure class='align$align'>";
    $html5 .= "<img src='$src[0]' alt='$alt' />";
    if ( $caption && $alt ) {
        $html5 .= "<figcaption><p class='image-description'><span>$alt: </span>$caption</p></figcaption>";
    }
    $html5 .= "</figure>";
    return $html5;
}
```

Any suggestion on what the source of the problem is? And how I can fix it? Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Disabling [wpautop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) does not solve the problem.

And I found this:

> But even if you’d use wp_get_attachment_image_src() or get_image_tag() to generate the image the WYSIWYG editor does not accept the figure element and will append a new line in front and after it everytime you save the article.
>   [Source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/insert-images-with-figurefigcaption/#comment-223910)

I tried without the html5 tags, and it still generates empty paragraph tags.

Comment: Check to see if wpautop is the culprit. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Comment: @Digitalchild Disabled wpautop to check, still the same problem..